# What make an SSL page unsecured?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a site which in ssl but i am not able to secure the page fully. https://econengine.com/_other_sites/fb/mtbusiness/directory.php

1. I have changed all resource links to https:// (facebook, twitter js)
2. All images loading from same domain using relative url.

I can't find out what makes it unsecure. I know I am missing something. Spent hours to find out but i can't. Can you see what is the problem? I don't have too much experience with ssl but i do know that if anything load form non secure url it will broke. But i can't seem to find what it is.

Comment: what do you mean it's broken?  I don't get any warnings

Comment: @jglouie The page is not fully secured click on the favicon to see the report.

Comment: Thanks, no idea what's wrong. :)  I'm curious so I'll favorite this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed something thats coming from Facebook - a FB canvas?

[Picture from Firefox](http://twitpic.com/5w5mop)

I don't think you can just 'change all the HTTPs to HTTPS either - do they have to actually be secure too!?

Comment: actually i am using this page in facebook page. So secure url is needed. Not sure why facebook pushing unsecured canvas.

Comment: Could this help? (SO Item)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935978/facebook-how-do-canvas-page-tabs-handle-https]

Comment: I think its not relevant. Thanks!

Comment: In that case - I'm out of ideas - not too familiar with the FB apps - sorry!

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help. I guess its some bug form facebook because i they injecting the unsecured url to the page.

Comment: Excuse the comment - But I doubt it's a bug on Facebook's part - I'd expect they'd have tested it....

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing obvious to me, however, as this is a duplicate question ;-) see the answers here [How do I figure out which parts of a web page are encrypted and which aren't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305538/how-do-i-figure-out-which-parts-of-a-web-page-are-encrypted-and-which-arent)